# Issue with cloning repository from GitHub Enterprise

Tags: git, github, repository, git-clone, github-for-windows

I've been working on a branch of a GitHub enterprise repository for a few weeks now, (and having no problem making commits/clones, etc.).

However, my GitHub has suddenly broken, and I cannot make any commits, changes, or even clone a repository. I have tried deleting and reinstalling GitHub, I have tried deleting my local repository and making a new clone, but I can't even clone the repository as I get the following error (Note: I had to remove the server URL and repo name for privacy):

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://SERVERURLHERE/SUBGROUPHERE/REPONAMEHERE.git/':
schannel: CertGetCertificateChain trust error CERT_TRUST_IS_PARTIAL_CHAIN
```

Comment: You have a possible key mismatch for the user (many possible reasons).Best thing is to generate a new private and public keys and put that in the user settings of the Github before you can do anything. Link on how to create keys https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.13/user/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same trouble. 
It solved my problem, to use the normal [**git command line**](https://git-scm.com/) instead of **Github-Desktop**